# How to make pricing section wp theme sticky

Tags: wordpress, sticky

I use wordpress theme by themepure harry portfolio here is the link

https://themeforest.net/item/harry-creative-agency-portfolio-wordpress-theme/43384980?gclid=CjwKCAjw3dCnBhBCEiwAVvLcu2ZLic1GEEI3PrK1PpXbKHLGnvqE_S3MfLtpQqs-QihBu7Vs1A4qQBoCV8IQAvD_BwE

so i have 2 column in wordpress.

I have a long content in left column and pricing element in right column. How do i make the pricing on the right column sticky when i am scrolling down.

thank you.[the screenshot what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KldIO.png)

I try to search on all options but i didnt find it